# One http request without auth cookies in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm try to create test script that emulate file signing. There is a big workflow that work under specified user with auth cookies, but one http-request must be queried without auth cookie. In real life this query executed by ActiveX plugin, it can't access cookies, and we do special method that return file for signing without authentication. And it cannot be done if auth cookies exists in query.

I understand that I can logout and login again after that request, but may be exist more elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to forget cookie just for one request, i suggest you to try the following :

1. Put your HTTP request in a **transaction Controller**.
2. In this controller, before your request, add a **HTTP Cookie
   Manager**

Look at the following link to put the best option for you :

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager

I don't know if you want to clear cookies, skip it just one time or other... But this configuration element should save you ;)

Comment: Ok, I'm try transaction controller tomorrow. I do same scenario with simple controller, it not works. I hope transaction controller will work as I need.

Comment: Hmm, not works. Like as simple controller. Cookies are exists in request. May be some configuration needed?